# Automatically changing DB fields

Tags: php

Is there any way to change automatically any fields in MySql database(PHP).In my program while adding a product its status will be 'new' in db,after 15 days it should be changed to 'Old'.Is Curl function helpful?

Comment: Use a CRON job, maybe?

Comment: Any useful references

Comment: google is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a cron job

The cron could execute a daily php script wich will query the database for old products

the query will look something like this

```
UPDATE from table t SET t.status_field = 'old' WHERE DATE_ADD( t.created_at_field, INTERVAL 15 DAY ) = CURDATE()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you give a brief idea of implementing crone in php(cakephp)

Comment: Are you using a server with cpanel ?